# How to read text from image using google vision in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, google-vision, image-text

I want to read texts from image using google vision text API. I have created my own UI which contains surfaceView. How to integrate google API

Comment: Post what you tried please

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-google-cloud-vision-api-in-android-apps--cms-29009 follow this link

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj  thanks